# Can I create user in Meteor without username or password?

Tags: meteor

I want to create a user that has no attributes but the ID, it seems I cant do that with `Accounts.createUser` since username and password are mandatory. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `Accounts.createUser` (package *accounts-password*) uses under the hood method `Accounts.insertNewDoc(options, user)` which is server side method from package *[accounts-base](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js)*.

You can create your own method :

```
Meteor.methods({
  "customCreateUser":function(options,user){
    // returns userId
    return Accounts.insertNewDoc(options, user)
  }
})
```

`Accounts.insertNewDoc(options, user)` doesn't have limitation to create user only when  `email` or `username` are passed in `options`.

However that limitation has `Accounts.createUser`:

```
  var username = options.username;
  var email = options.email;
  if (!username && !email)
    throw new Meteor.Error(400, "Need to set a username or email");
```

[line 671-674](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-password/password_server.js)

Comment: what about logging in with a custom field: say I have `foo: 'bla'` and if the user enters that value of `foo` correctly he is logged in. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't have answer out of the box for this question, need to digg into `accounts` packages. Please create new question and then I try to find out.